# What is this proof doing? Projections

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am reading notes in my notebook and we are trying to prove that $P_M$ the projection onto $M$ has the property $\langle x - P_M x, P_M x \rangle = 0$ and let $\{v_i \}$ be the orthonormal basis for $M$. and $x - P_Mx = x - \sum_{i \geq 1} \langle x, v_i\rangle v_i$ where $P_Mx = \sum_{i \geq 1} \langle x, v_i\rangle v_i$

> $\langle x - P_M x, v_j \rangle = \langle x - \sum_{i \geq 1} \langle x, v_i\rangle v_i, v_j  \rangle = \langle x, v_j \rangle - \langle \sum_{i \geq 1} \langle x, v_i\rangle v_i, v_j \rangle = \langle x, v_j \rangle - \langle x, v_j \rangle = 0$

Can someone tell me how suddenly $P_Mx = v_j$?

**EDIT**: $M$ is a subspce of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What are the spaces have you considered? $M$ must be subspace given vector space?

Comment: I will edit to clarify. Thank you for asking

Comment: Oh that's funny, I thought I actually wrote out that one in the beginning. It is for $M$

Comment: $\langle x-P_Mx,P_Mx\rangle$ is an expression, not a property ... And how did you define $P_M$ in the first place?

Comment: See edit please. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this hint may work for you.

$P_M$ is a projector onto $M$, so the image of this projector is $M.$ i.e. $P_M (\mathbb{R}^m) = M$. So if $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is any vector it must satisfy $P_M (x) = v_{i}$, if ${v_i}$ is the basis of $M$.

Comment: OKay, but what happened to the other terms?

Comment: @sizz What are those terms you are not clear about?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $P_Mx = \sum_{i \geq 1} \langle x, v_i\rangle v_i$?

Comment: Because $\{ v_i \}$ is the basis not $v_i$